# Is it possible to format a link for an ftp, windows network, or windows path location?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm creating an internal bot that's running in Microsoft Teams.

I want it to be able to give people a link to the location of the latest installer of our software.

This link would either be an ftp, windows network, or windows path.

When I try putting any of these locations into the link format (either `<link_location>` or `[link text](link_location)`, it shows up in Teams looking like a link, but it is not clickable.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you try the official markdown format which is `[linkText](link_location)`?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: Yes, I said in my post that I did.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if you had tried this or [link] and (link) separately

Comment: Can you also add which on version(s) of teams you tried (web, desktop client for windows/mac, etc) and did you try a "normal" web link?

Comment: Desktop client for windows.  Normal web links work just fine.

Comment: I tried this myself and got the same results, I sent an email to the MS teams team to ask if this is intentional or not.

Answer (score 1):

Links must be https. Network paths and ftp’s are not supported.  There are no plans to support them in the future because of the risk of security and phishing attacks.

Comment: Thanks Jason for MS feedback